# Are words like "five-minute" or "two-storey" considered phrasal words?

Tags: morphology

In my Morphology course, my lecturer introduced something called "phrasal word". Basically, a phrasal word has the structure of a phrase, yet it can function like a word. For example, "jack-in-the-box" is structured like a noun phrase with the head noun "jack" and prepositional phrase modifier "in the box", but it can function as a word "They jumped up and down like jack-in-the-boxes". The same goes for "a **couldn't-care-less** attitude", etc. My question is that: are words like "**five-minute**", containing a head noun "minute" and a number "five", also phrasal words because they can function like adjectives?
The coursebook I'm using is "An introduction to English Morphology" - A. Carstairs & McCarthy.

Comment: I would avoid the term 'phrasal word'. In my experience they are called **compound words**. They may be nouns: "He behaved like a jack-in-the-box" (noun), or adjectives: "It was a five-minute wonder"; "He had a couldn't-care-less attitude to the problem". They are single words, though, not syntactic constructions. Note that in. for example "jack-in-the-box", "Jack" is the head (the central element) with a PP as dependent.

Comment: "Five-minute" or "two-storey" are compound adjectives, each of them lacks the formant, namely the plural suffix that organizes the two words into a phrase, the actual phrases would be "five minute**s**" and "two storey**s**".

Comment: Incidentally, we find 'nonce-formations', such as "do-it-yourself skills" / "the buy-me glitter of the duty-free shop".  Many are simply concocted 'on-the-hoof', such as "the custard-pie-in-your-face sketch"